# I have a dataframe which consists certain dates and respective values

Tags: python, python-3.x

My challenge is that if any date is to be checked against a dates in the dataframe and it should be able to pull the respective value that which holds. I can show this to you

```
Date           Value
4/6/2006    1,500,000
4/6/2007    1,600,000
4/6/2008    1,650,000
4/6/2009    1,750,000
4/6/2010    1,800,000
4/6/2011    1,800,000
4/6/2012    1,500,000
4/6/2013    1,500,000
4/6/2014    1,250,000
4/6/2015    1,250,000
4/6/2016    1,000,000
4/6/2017    1,000,000
4/6/2018    1,030,000
```

the date sometimes isn't exact same as the one in the field, it may vary and the value nearest to that date should be pulled. It should be in a loop.

Comment: You can employ a minimum difference search algorithm to find the nearest date

Comment: can you give example of the dates that you want to be pulled? and the expected output?

Comment: for example if any date between 4/6/2006 and 4/6/2007 is given, output should be this dates 4/6/2006 value which in this case is 1,50,000.

Comment: and if the date exceeds 4/6/2007 and stays upto 4/6/2008 then its 1,600,000